# In transformers of ViT model, last_hidden_state is not equal to hidden_states[-1]

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

When input the same image, in Google ViT model output.last_hidden_state is not equal to output.hidden_states[-1] ?
I tried in Bert， the outputs are the same.

feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')

```
model = ViTModel.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
inputs = feature_extractor(images=[image], return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(pixel_values=inputs['pixel_values'], output_hidden_states=True)

vec1 = outputs.hidden_states[-1][0, 0, :]
vec2 = outputs.last_hidden_state[0, 0, :]
```

in my mind, vec1 should be the same as vec2. But the fact is they are not the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the layernorm is applied to the last_hidden_state.

The following is an excerpt of the last 15 lines or so of ViTModel's forward method. For sequence_output, which is assigned to last_hidden_state, layernorm is applied to the output from the encoder.

```
sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0]
sequence_output = self.layernorm(sequence_output)
pooled_output = self.pooler(sequence_output) if self.pooler is not None else None

if not return_dict:
    head_outputs = (sequence_output, pooled_output) if pooled_output is not None else (sequence_output,)
    return head_outputs + encoder_outputs[1:]

return BaseModelOutputWithPooling(
    last_hidden_state=sequence_output,
    pooler_output=pooled_output,
    hidden_states=encoder_outputs.hidden_states,
    attentions=encoder_outputs.attentions,
)
```

If we apply layernorm to hidden_state[-1], we can confirm that the same value is obtained.
Please refer to the notebook I made in Colab.
[vit_huggingface](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12OmNW5dZsARio0Tzu11ParHxblOoez7u?usp=sharing)